# Core Audio SDK for Xcode 3.2

Tags: xcode, macos, sdk, osx-snow-leopard

I'm a newbie and trying to work through this tutorial:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/musicaudio/conceptual/audiounitprogrammingguide/Tutorial-BuildingASimpleEffectUnitWithAGenericView/Tutorial-BuildingASimpleEffectUnitWithAGenericView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003278-CH5-SW4

I'm using OSX 10.6.8 Snow Leopard so could only install XCode 3.2.6. I can't seem to find Core Audio SDK anywhere and the only solutions I've been able to find are all for XCode 4 and above.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I'm very new to all this so layman's terms would be much appreciated where possible.

Thanks,
Jess

Comment: You don't have `/Developer/Extras/CoreAudio/` directory on your startup volume ?

Comment: Yeah I figured it out in the end, apologies! I wasn't looking in the right place. D'oh!